# How to add more value when we submit on React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to add more values onSubmit function, I try like:

```
const onSubmit = (data, value) => {
   console.log(data);
   console.log(value);
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit(someValue))}>
  <input id="file1" name="file1" type="file" ref={register}/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

For example, I try to add some value to onSubmit function and when I console log, it is undefined. Is there any way to put value into onSubmit.

Comment: When you render the component you're immediately calling `onSubmit` with `data` of `10` and `value` of `undefined`, and passing the result (also `undefined`) to `handleSubmit`. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, I know. but I need some value to be validated on the function. So, I try to add that value to this function. when I call it.

Comment: Please give a [mre], without more context it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I found the way, anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: what way do you definitely find @JackVenevankham ? I'm trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a value before passing it to the `onSubmit` handler function, you can modify the data object within the `handleSubmit` function.
still, work even if those properties do not correspond to any of the form's input fields.

Here's how you can add more value before it is passed to the `onSubmit` handler:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
   console.log(data);
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {
  data.someValue = "someValue property";
  onSubmit(data);
})}>
  <input id="file1" name="file1" type="file" ref={register}/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: actually this doesn't seem to work. What gets submitted is not the data itself, but a representation of the data, which you can get from getValues(). So even if you update data in your code example, the change won't be visible. As far as I have been able to determine, the only way to get this to work is to declare a hidden field called "someValue" and update that.